# Threadpool Management in Web Applicatios

Tags: java, web-applications, threadpool

As a part of my project I need to implement a thereadpool manager. My project is a web application where many clients will be requesting many services. How can I get more information about the allocation of threads from threadpools to the client processes? Can anyone please provide some guidelines for effective implementation?

Comment: give us more info about what you specifically want to do

Answer (score 1):

The good news is that you do not have to implement any thread pool in web application. Server side of Web application is typically implemented using one of web technologies and is expected to run into container that already implement thread pool.

Even if you are implementing your application using plain JSP or servlets everything is under control and server already does all this work.

If you still need thread pool use java concurrency package. It has everything including very strong configurable thread pool.

Answer (score 1):

The thread pool of a web application is normally handled by the web container running the webapp (Tomcat, Jetty, etc.). See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/executor.html for Tomcat, for example.